# firebase onAuthStateChanged very slow in react-native with JS debugger enabled

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a react-native app and using firebase authentication. 
`onAuthStateChanged` is the function I have a problem with:

```
console.time("onAuthStateChanged");
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  console.timeEnd("onAuthStateChanged");
});
```

The problem is that it takes anywhere from 4 to 6 seconds for the callback to be called which results in a very poor developper experience.
This happens only when I have the JS debugger enabled.
Without the JS debugger, it is pretty fast (under 1 second).

I tried on chrome and firefox.

Any idea on how to improve this ?

Comment: Debugger slows things down almost everything in RN. If u turn it down or use signed apk, there's no problem. The auth check needs just a moment. Its normal.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that using `react-native-firebase` instead improved things a lot.